# Running cuda socket program

Tags: c, sockets, cuda

I want to create a socket connected directly to the gpu.
I would like to send data from a server to the gpu without spending a copy/moving time from host to device.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have suitable network hardware and are willing to write your own device driver for your network adaptor, then [maybe](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html#axzz4K15QrVmc). [Several](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect) Infiniband and iWARP adapter vendors can have engineered such support for their products.

But realistically, no.

Comment: Do you know how can i do it, and how much it will take?

Comment: I write you to tell you that i just had the same idea. However, and by guessing , all computer parts are connected through the PCI of the motherboard. The GPU is not connected to the network card directly unless you manufacture a link or cable between them.